# Problem with passing Model into compiled Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem, with i compiled my Razor Views and try to pass here model.
So, this is an error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcApplication2.PluginHelloWorld.HelloWorldPluginViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication2.PluginHelloWorld.HelloWorldPluginViewModel'
```

I have plugin .cs file (Method of controller):

```
public class PluginHelloWorldController : PluginController
{
    public PluginHelloWorldController(string pluginDirectory) : base(pluginDirectory) { }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RelativeView("index.cshtml", new HelloWorldPluginViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HelloWorldPluginViewModel model)
    {
        return RelativeView("index.cshtml", model);
    }
}
```

And plugin controller method:

```
public abstract class PluginController : Controller
{
    protected string PluginDirectory;

    // pluginDirectory will have a value like '~/extensions/plugins/rating/'
    public PluginController(string pluginDirectory)
    {
        if (pluginDirectory.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            PluginDirectory = pluginDirectory;
        }
        else
        {
            PluginDirectory = pluginDirectory + "/";
        }
    }
    public ViewResult RelativeView(string viewName, object model)
    {
        viewName = PluginDirectory + viewName;

        return base.View(viewName, model);
    }
}
```

So, here i have an error:

```
return base.View(viewName, model);
```

I want to pass Model into this method (.cs file of my View)

```
    public class _Page_index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<MvcApplication2.PluginHelloWorld.HelloWorldPluginViewModel>
    {
#line hidden

        public _Page_index_cshtml()
        {
        }
        protected System.Web.HttpApplication ApplicationInstance
        {
            get
            {
                return ((System.Web.HttpApplication)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
            }
        }
        public override void Execute()
        {
            WriteLiteral("\r\n<h2>Hello!</h2>\r\n<p>");
            Write(Html.TextBox("hello", Model.foo));
            WriteLiteral("</p>");
        }
    }
```

---

### As i can see here, it works: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/ASP.NET/Forum/openforum/OpenForum/Core/Views/Forum/Index.cs.htm (passing Model into compiled View, but i have this strange error =)

I changed code like this:

```
    public class _Page_index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic>
    {
#line hidden

        public _Page_index_cshtml()
        {
        }
        protected System.Web.HttpApplication ApplicationInstance
        {
            get
            {
                return ((System.Web.HttpApplication)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
            }
        }
        public override void Execute()
        {

    var ViewModel = Model as MvcApplication2.PluginHelloWorld.HelloWorldPluginViewModel;    

WriteLiteral("\r\n<h2>Hello!</h2>\r\n<p>");
Write(ViewModel.foo);
//Write(Html.TextBox("hello", ViewModel.foo));
WriteLiteral("</p>");
        }
    }
```

And now there is an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

---

### So, i tried to check ViewModel and ViewModel.foo on null and it's true. Looks like, problem with passing null, but why =\

So, this is the last point before error:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RelativeView("index.cshtml", new HelloWorldPluginViewModel());
}
```

other words:

```
public ViewResult RelativeView(string viewName, object model)
    {
        viewName = PluginDirectory + viewName;

        return base.View(viewName, model);
    }
```

And model **is not null** here.

But when i check it here, in Execute method:

```
public class _Page_index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<MvcApplication2.PluginHelloWorld.HelloWorldPluginViewModel>
    {
#line hidden

        public _Page_index_cshtml()
        {
        }
        protected System.Web.HttpApplication ApplicationInstance
        {
            get
            {
                return ((System.Web.HttpApplication)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
            }
        }
        public override void Execute()
        {
            WriteLiteral("\r\n<h2>Hello!</h2>\r\n<p>");
            Write(Html.TextBox("hello", Model.foo));
            WriteLiteral("</p>");
        }
    }
```

Model **is null**...

### Ofc, it maybe works with interface, i haven't tried it yet, but what's the problem with simple object passing =\

Still don't know where is an error.
Mb i have to register my passing viewmodel here:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    container = new WindsorContainer();
    // register 'normal' controllers
    container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller")).Configure((ConfigureDelegate)(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient)));

    // string is the route path
    // type is the plugin controller type
    // it maps routes like '/admin/plugins/rating/{action}' to Crash.PageRating.PageRatingController
    Dictionary<string, Type> pluginTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    // location of the plugins
    var allPluginsDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/extensions/plugins/"));
    foreach(var dir in allPluginsDir.GetDirectories())
    {
        string pluginDir = string.Format("~/extensions/plugins/{0}/", dir.Name);

        // loop through all dll files, though only one should exist per directory
        foreach(var dll in dir.GetFiles("*.dll"))
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dll.FullName);
            // register compiled razor views
            // e.g. 'settings.cshtml' is registered as '~/extensions/plugins/rating/settings.cshtml'
            BoC.Web.Mvc.PrecompiledViews.ApplicationPartRegistry.Register(assembly, pluginDir);

            // only one controller per plugin in this case
            var controllerType = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(PluginController).IsAssignableFrom(t)).FirstOrDefault();
            if(controllerType != null)
            {
                // register controller
                // pass pluginDir to the constructor
                container.Register(Component.For(controllerType).DependsOn(new { pluginDirectory = pluginDir }).LifeStyle.Transient);
                // admin route url
                var pluginUrl = string.Format("plugins/{0}/{{action}}", dir.Name);
                // map admin route to controller
                pluginTypes.Add(pluginUrl, controllerType);
                RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("plugin_" + dir.Name, pluginUrl, new {controller=controllerType.Name.Replace("Controller",""),action="Index" },new[]{controllerType.Namespace});

            }
        }
    }

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    // Controller factory
    var controllerFactory = new CrashControllerFactory(container.Kernel,pluginTypes);
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);            
}
```

### Looks like i have to do it, but dont know how =\

Can anybody help to pass Model into compiled Razor View?

Comment: Try casting object with (type)Object and not with "AS" keyword. var ViewModel = (MvcApplication2.PluginHelloWorld.HelloWorldPluginViewModel) Model

Answer (score -3):

You can use `@viewbag.xxxx`

Anything you want to pass to the "view", you just type `viewbag.xxx`
then in view, you can use `@viewbag.xxx`.

It will show it, whether is it a view data or database data.